# Is there a way to spawn electron Browser Windows that are just chromium browsers?

Tags: electron

I am currently creating a multi-browser emulation software. This software serves as a way to emulate multiple users through a single machine.

I want to be able to use electron’s browser window functionality to spawn chromium web browser instances. Is there support for this? I am aware that I could simply spawn sub processes, but native support would be much more convenient. Thanks!

Comment: "This software serves as a way to emulate multiple users through a single machine." - using Electron may backfire because Electron does not behave identically to Chrome and Chromium. It also tends to lag behind Chrome and NodeJS by about a month.

Comment: I am only using electron to build the user interface. Like I said, I could just build something on top of chromium and keep it away from the UI code to keep versions tighter like you said. Is there electron functionality for this though?

Comment: To clarify, I would use CEF to get the job done.